# Weight lifting and dental care

Tags: weightlifting

Are there any effects when it comes to weight lifting in our dental or teeth? Does lifting heavy will cause toothache?

Comment: It might indirectly if you clench your teeth really hard when you strain on a hard lift.

Comment: @Tyler does lifting while having a toothache will cause any problem with the blood circulation in our gums?

Comment: I have a friend with a chipped tooth from a clean he caught wrong.

Comment: I have experienced an increased flow of blood throughout the body after lifting that has alerted me to a dental issue through the subtlety of throbbing pain. I ignored the issue and it turned out to be a cracked filling (over 15 years old) and since I ignored it - turned into a root canal. Call your dentist IMMEDIATELY and talk to him about fitting a mouth guard for weight lifting if you're a grinder/clincher, otherwise you might have an underlying dental condition that needs immediate attention.

Comment: [Jaw pain when exercising](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Warning-Signs.html) could be a lesser known warning sign of heart attack which is a medical emergency. Although this may be an unlikely cause in your case it would be wise to mention this to your doctor.

Answer (score 4):

If you've experienced toothache during lifting, I'm inclined to believe there is an underlying problem. Many lifters to indeed clench their jaw during particularly heavy lifts, and this might be interpreted as toothache.

Certain heavy lifts like deadlifts and pullups put strain on muscles in the neck/jaw area, which in some cases could affect muscles and tendons in the tempomandibular area.

Even so, it's still far from anything that should cause concern for your teeth during lifts, but it's worth it to "keep an eye" on whether or not you're gritting your teeth together when performing.

Answer (score -1):

Heavy lifting does not cause toothache. Unless you are pulling the weights up with your teeth, then it might.
It is very, very unlikely that you will press your teeth together so hard during a lift, that you will damage them. It just will not happen.
Don't worry, your teeth are safe.